# HABTM filter_or_create usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This question is asking a similar thing: [Rails: Has and belongs to many (HABTM) -- create association without creating other records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730493/rails-has-and-belongs-to-many-habtm-create-association-without-creating-ot) but I'm new to Rails and get apply it to my problem.

I can create a new `Location` and a new association between `User and Location easily:

```
@location = Location.new(params[:location].merge(:user_ids => current_user.id))
```

How can I change this so:

- a new `Location` and association is created if the `Location` does not exist
- a new association is created if the `Location` already exists

?

My Models are like this:

`Location`:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :user_ids
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

`User`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
end
```

So I want to know how to create just an association and how to check if I should create just an association.

My association table just has `location_id` and a `user_id` fields.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at
AR::B#first_or_create 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-first_or_create
AR::B#first_or_initialize http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-first_or_initialize