# How to seed a database with a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, many-to-many

I am trying to build a seed file that populates a state, county and zip table. Zips can exist in multiple states and counties. Counties and states contain multiple zips. My State and County  seed works fine, but I am having problems seeding my zips. When I use the seed file without trying to make a reference to the relationship, it works, but I receive an error when I try to establish a connection. I assume I am just using the .create method incorrectly for a many to many relationship.

**Models**

```
  class County < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :state
   has_and_belongs_to_many :zips
  end 

class State < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :county
    has_and_belongs_to_many :zips
end 

class Zip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :counties
  has_and_belongs_to_many :states
end
```

**Migrations**

```
class CreateStates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :states do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :abbreviation

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateCounties < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :counties do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :state, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateZips < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :zips do |t|
      t.string :code
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :zips_counties, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :zip
      t.belongs_to :county
    end

    create_table :zips_states, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :zip
      t.belongs_to :state
    end
  end
end
```

**Seed FILE - note.. this is not the final version, I am just trying to make anything work that includes the many to many relationship. '5' does exist**

```
County.delete_all
State.delete_all
Zip.delete_all
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!('states')
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!('counties')

CSV.foreach("lib/tasks/state_table.csv") do |state|
    name = state[0]
    abbr = state[1]
    State.find_or_create_by!(name: name, abbreviation: abbr)
end

CSV.foreach("lib/tasks/counties.csv") do |county|
    name = county[0]
    state = county[1]
    County.create(name: name, state: State.find_by(abbreviation: state))
end

CSV.foreach("lib/tasks/zip_codes.csv") do |zip|
    code = zip[0]
    county = zip[1]
    state = zip[2]
    #puts state
    if County.find_by(name: county) != nil && County.find_by(name: county).state.abbreviation == state
        #puts State.find_by(abbreviation: state).abbreviation == state
        #puts County.find_by(name: county).state.abbreviation
        #puts State.find_by(abbreviation: state).id
        Zip.create(code: code, state: State.find(5))
    end
end
```

**Finally, the error when I run "rake db:seed"**

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: state

Comment: Check out this answer perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730493/rails-has-and-belongs-to-many-habtm-create-association-without-creating-ot

Answer (score 2):

The error is complaining that you are trying to set the state attribute, which Zip doesn't have.  Zip has a collection called states.  I think you want to say:

```
Zip.create(code: code, states: [ State.find(5) ])
```