# Can I override "create" with "first_or_create"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently have `Scene` and `Role` models, and a `SceneRole` association table joining them:

```
class Scene < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scene_role
  has_many :roles, through: :scene_role
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scene_role
  has_many :scenes, through: :scene_role
end

class SceneRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :scene
  belongs_to :role

  validates_presence_of :scene_id
  validates_presence_of :role_id

  validates_uniqueness_of :scene, :scope => :role
end
```

I want to ensure that any same scene-role relationship is unique. But I also want to gracefully handle attempts to add a `Role` to a `Scene` when the relationship already exists without getting an error:  `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Scene has already been taken`

My test code:

```
role = Role.new(name: "Big Bossman")
scene = Scene.new(name: "Arena")

scene.roles << role # success
scene.roles << role # Exception
```

Is it possible to override `create` with the behavior of `first_or_create`?  I believe that would solve my problem. However, if there is a better way to accomplish the same result I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is possible with [monkey patching](http://culttt.com/2015/06/17/what-is-monkey-patching-in-ruby/) but it's a very bad idea.** You would be asking for major trouble down the road when you or someone else expects the code to behave in a certain default way. What if the requirements change and you remove the validation? You would silently never be able to create multiple records with `create` because `first_or_create` would always find the existing one.

The best alternative would be to check if the `role` already exists in `scene.roles`. For example:

```
scene.roles.include?(role) ? false : scene.roles << role
# does scene.roles include role? if yes: do nothing, if not: add role
```

Or do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4730577/1241782).

Comment: I created an `add_role` method as you suggested and it's working great; no monkey patching required.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add this in a `before_validation` method that wouldn't actually raise an error, but would remove the previous role if it exists. In this you would be able to handle edge cases.

```
class SceneRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :single_relation

  def single_relation
    # Checks new and stored records for duplicate and removes it
    # Might want to have this on both scene and role instead of here
  end
end
```